# A question involving tangent planes

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was asked to locate the points on the surface $z=4x^2-y^3$ where the tangent place is parallel to the plane $16x+27y+4z=47$.

I might need to be walked through this. I already found the partial derivatives of the surface equation and found the gradient to be $<8x, -3y^2, -1>$. And I supposed to use the components $<16, 27, 4>$ to find the components of the gradient, and  set the equation of the tangent plane equal to $47$?

Comment: Yes, until the last part: you can ignore $47$ as any plane $16x+27y+4z=c$ is parallel to the given one.

Comment: Thank you berci. Also, for the equation of the tangent plant, will the points x0, y0, and z0 be the components <16, 27, 4>?

Comment: You need to find where the normal is _parallel_ to $\langle16,27,4\rangle$. The gradient that you’ve come up with can’t be equal to this anywhere since $4\ne-1$.